# How must an object diagram look like?

Tags: uml, object-diagram

I searched the web, but I find a bunch of very different diagrams. Most of them don't even look like object diagrams. They have no object's value. I want to know how I must draw an object diagram in such a way, that my prof won't tell me it's absolutely wrong. Any good tutorial link is highly appreciated!

Comment: I recommend attending your lectures.

FWIW, you don't usually draw object graphs in design diagrams, class diagrams are much more common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [developer.com](http://www.developer.com/img/articles/2003/06/17/UML0503.jpg))</sub>

An object uml diagram probably should look like this. You can find lots of examples on the net. Good luck

Comment: google.com type "object diagram" hit enter and click "Images" ftw! Sometimes it's we are like concierge for google rejects

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking of a class diagram, that shows the relationship between classes (not object instances), right?

[UML (Unified Modeling Language)](http://www.uml.org/) is the standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Object diagrams tend to have limited use (they're usually working for other diagrams).  I suspect you want a class or communication diagram.  A class diagram will have fields but no values, while a communication diagram includes messages.

This is an [object diagram](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/objectDiagram.htm).  There is a more detailed description as part of [this tutorial](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/2223551).

Read [this page](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm) for the different uses of class diagrams, and [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/) for a tutorial.

[Here are](http://www.xpdian.com/Thecommunicationdiagram.html) two examples of communication diagrams.